# Anti spam script not detecting variable for some reason (what I got out of it)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function commentpost(){
  var allow = true;
  var game = "<?php echo $game ?>";
  var name = $("input#name").val();
  var comment = $("textarea#comment").val();
  var date =  currentdate();
  var dataString = "postdate=" + date + "&game=" + game + "&name=" + name + "&comment=" + comment;
  if(name && comment && allow){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../php/addcomment.php",
      data: dataString,
      success: function(){
        updatecomments();
        //important part here V
        allow = false;
        setTimeout(function(){
          allow = true; 
          // alert(allow);
        }, 5000);
        // alert(allow);
        //important part here ^
      }
    });
  }
  //important part here V
  else if ((!name || !comment) && allow){
    alert("Please fill out both the Name and Comment fields");
  }
  else if (!allow){
    alert("Commenting has been limited to 5 seconds in between to pevent spamming.");
  }
  //important part here ^
}
```

I have a small, basic comment script on a website I am creating. That all works fine, but I am trying to prevent the submit button from being spammed. This seems like it SHOULD work to me but for some reason it just is not, I think somehow due to the way I use "allow".

Comment: Put the `var allow = true;` **outside** of this function. Otherwise, it's being instantiated as `true` every time `commentPost` is being called, and therefore will always start out as `true`. If you want to have a global flag for this ability, put it in the global scope

Comment: Shouldn't `allow = false` be placed immediately before the ajax request to prevent it from sending many ajax requests? also, don't use alerts to debug asynchronous events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a scope problem with your allow variable: You create it anew and set it to true whenever commentPost() is called, so it will always be true when you check its value.

You need something like this:

```
var allow = true;

function commentpost(){
  //...
  if(name && comment && allow){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../php/addcomment.php",
      data: dataString,
      success: function(){
        updatecomments();
        allow = false;
        setTimeout(function(){
          allow = true; 
        }, 5000);
      }
    });
  }
```

Of course, I wouldn't recommend declaring allow globally, but without knowing the context of commentpost it's hard to say where it should be stored.

Comment: Ugh, I feel like an idiot, It is just one of those moments where you can't seem to find the simplest mistake. I seem to have those too much. Thank you.